# How to replace the body of a reply to an email and keep signature?

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to reply to an email without including the original email, but include the sender as the recipient, the subject, and my signature.

Currently I have `Set objDoc = ActiveInspector.WordEditor`. I tried looking for the body of the email here, so I can replace it with other text.

I would like to retain the Subject of the email I am replying to, the Sender, and the Recipient.

Here is the code I have for my current reply:

```
With oReply
    .BCC = bccField
    .CC = ccField
    .HTMLBody = "<HTML><Body><span>my reply here</span><Body></HTML>" & .HTMLBody & "<span>" & "Additional stuff" & "</span>"
End With
```

I tried taking out the .HTMLBody in between the `<span>`s, which does take out the original user's message but also takes out my signature.

Comment: Create a new email just before this line. This will be opening along with your signature. Store that Signature in a variable and later call it in the place of .htmlbody. This is how i manage to get the signature

Comment: @manoj0790 would you be able to give me an example in code?

Comment: Could you paste the full code?

Comment: @manoj0790 unfortunately i cant. all i know is the .htmlbody contains both the signature and the user's response and i need to discard the user's response but not the signature.

Comment: I can try to modify the existing to make it work but not to write something from scratch.

Comment: @manoj0790 that might be good enough. thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `reply` functionality, just create a new mailItem and transfer the details over.

Example below uses the original email. So wherever you have `Set oReply = (something).Reply` you will replace or update that with `Set originalMailItem = (Something)`.  This `(something)` should be the original mail you are attempting to reply to.

In order to effectively insert the signature, we have to `.Display` the mailItem. Otherwise outlook will note generate the signature. Make sure the signature settings are correct on your outlook client to default to the desired signature for new mail items.

```
Set newMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'Create a new mail instead of replying to existing

With newMail
    .Display
    .HTMLBody = "<HTML><Body><span>my reply here</span><Body></HTML>" _
    & "<span>" & "Additional stuff" & "</span>" _
    & .HTMLBody 'HTMLBody already contains the signature once the email was displayed so we just tack it onto the end.
    .To = originalMailItem.SenderEmailAddress
    .CC = originalMailItem.CC
    .BCC = originalMailItem.BCC
    .Subject = originalMailItem.Subject
    '.Send     'To send the reply
End With
```